# Find/replace text from WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin, part of which requires replacing the label on the WordPress registration page username field. I've been trying to figure it out, and I think something like the following would work...

```
if( $('body').hasClass('login') ) $('form#registerform label').each(function(){ if( $(this).text() == 'Username' ) $(this).text('whateverIwant'); });
```

Problem is, I can't figure out how to get it to actually run the aforementioned code... Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your plugin try this:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'login_form', 'PATHTOYOURSCRIPT', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

Also your JS will probably want to look like this:

```
(function($) {
    if( $('body').hasClass('login') ) {
        var username = document.createElement("input");
        username.type = 'text';
        username.name = 'log';
        username.id = 'user_login';
        username.className = 'input';
        username.size = '20';
        username.tabIndex = '10';
        $('label').each(
            function() {
                if( $(this).text().trim() == 'Username' ) {
                    $(this).html('whateveriwant<br>');
                    $(this).append(username);
                }
            }
        );
    }
})( jQuery );
```